# Using Drupal Commons, how can I create a node of a specific content type on group creation?

Tags: organic-groups, entities, 7

I am looking for a way to create a node of a specific content type at the same time as a group is created.

So basically, when a group is created a node of type my-content-type is created at the same time with og_group_ref pre-populated to associate it with the group just created...

I don't think there is a module for this, so... any pointers on to how to code this?

Comment: Ok, for anyone else trying to do this, its possible with the [Drupal Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) module... Drupal never ceases to amaze me..

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you can use Rules to answer your question?  Just saying that you can make a rule doesn't really help out future users.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution:

Obviously you need to download and install Rules, then:

1. Add an event:

After saving new content of type *Group*

2
. Add conditions:

Any conditions you want here..

3.Add Actions:

a) **Create a new entity**

- Parameter: *Entity type*: Node, *Content type*: ContentTypeYouWantToCreate, *Title*: YourTitle, *Author*: TheAuthor
- Provides variables: Created entity (entity_created)

b) **Save entity**

Parameter: *Entity*: [entity-created], *Force saving immediately*: true

c) **Add entity to group**

Parameter: *Entity*: [entity-created], *Group*: [node]

your content type should now be created when you create a new group - it will also be added to the newly created group.

Done!